# Wireshark RST against TCP Zero Window

Tags: sockets, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump, lync

During application sharing with Microsoft Lync Client (Mac OS X), TCP ACK with RST flag is sent from my application end to Lync end against TCP Zero Window packets and call gets dropped.

[image]

FYI:

```
My Application End: 172.16.6.106:55848
Lync End (Remote): 172.16.14.58:18627
Environment: 
My Application End: Centos/Linux
Lync End: Mac OSX
Shared Over Wifi.
```

**EDIT**

[Wireshark TCP Dump](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kh1dsoi9xwvm46l/20150915_filter_Call_Drop.pcapng?dl=0)

Lync BYE message to my Application:

```
BYE sip:172.16.6.106:48038;transport=tls;ms-opaque=28c9d310c1;ms-received-cid=BEED00;grid SIP/2.0
ms-user-logon-data: RemoteUser
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 172.16.6.252:5061;branch=z9hG4bKB5634D63.2E095CFF28141DF6;branched=FALSE;ms-internal-info="agIDti2ZsTK4cWfhAGG1qbj2usseveww7YKemPpN3Jvhv_XAkuuCofIQAA"
Max-Forwards: 67
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.2.3:51217;branch=z9hG4bK77E14D58.4A2E43E7B13911D2;branched=FALSE;ms-received-port=51217;ms-received-cid=BEE600
Authentication-Info: NTLM qop="auth", opaque="4207B105", srand="D2C8703A", snum="21", rspauth="010000008bc2daa4dc3b08b864000000", targetname="Lync-FE.LTN2013-Dev.local", realm="SIP Communications Service", version=4
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.2.4:50740;branch=z9hG4bKFF62C04C.B8AD61CF28131DF6;branched=FALSE;ms-received-port=50740;ms-received-cid=1117700
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 172.16.14.58:30689;received=172.16.14.58;ms-received-port=57719;ms-received-cid=BEE400
From: "" <sip:test1@ltn2013-dev.net>;epid=48777ee2e9;tag=dd8ced12ab
To: <sip:ilanaroom@ltn2013-dev.net>;tag=1442263920;epid=14422639
Call-ID: RkdVRZrTUlhKLke0Et9MiVaJTOJd5UMJKljncCC1
CSeq: 1 BYE
User-Agent: UCCAPI/4.0.7323.0 MC/14.0.5093.11 (Microsoft Lync for Mac 2011)
ms-client-diagnostics: 34; reason="Call terminated on a mid-call media failure where both endpoints are remote";MediaDebug="Diag:LastError:time out,time:3651253182890;LastRTP Seq:30662,SeqDelta:1,time:3651253152751;LastRTCP time:3651253151390;Last transport receive error:0x0,time:0;Last transport send error:0x0,time:0;"
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The capture excerpt shown indicates that Lync is sending data to your Ap Ok but, for whatever reason, is unwilling to accept any data from your Ap (since the advertised window from 172.16.14.58 is 0).

One possibilityfor the RST from your Ap: your Ap has data to send to Lync but can't (since the win = 0) and eventually gives up.

Obviously, this doesn't help much other than to suggest that there's a problem with the Lync end.  It's possible that examining a complete capture would provide more information.

For example: was the Ap previously able to send data ? What was the history of the window advertised by Lync ?   and so on.

Update:

*Examining the capture you've posted a link to:

It looks quite normal (other than the zero-window stuff at the end).

Starting at about the 91 sec point, the Lync server stops accepting data (win=0), sends some short messages back to your client and then your client sends an RST to the server 30 secs after the server stops accepting data.

So: there's not really any info in the capture which indicates anything much about what's going on with the Lync server.

I do note that just before the win=0 from the server, the windows advertised by the server are smaller than the range advertised previously. (Note: I expect that the actual window size is larger than that seemingly advertised because there's a "window size scale factor" greater than 1 involved. Wireshark doesn't know the scale factor since the original TCP connection establishment handshake is not part of the capture).

Comment: I have added the tcp dump and BYE message of Lync end. Please let me know if you can find anything.